# Far better than

Tags: grammar, sentence

Can we say:

> He is far better than you are in rain dance

Or there is something grammaticaly wrong?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it. (Well, actually, some might argue that it should be "at rain dancing" or "in the rain dance".)

Comment: @HotLicks so "in the rain dance" is better to use or what?

Comment: The expression is 'good at [doing something]', so 'better at rain dancing' or ''at [doing] the rain dance'.